# fail2ban not banning ssh

Tags: fail2ban

Trying to setup fail2ban sshd on Ubuntu 20.

```
# fail2ban-client status sshd
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 8
   |- Total banned:     8
   `- Banned IP list:   112.85.42.185 114.198.132.36 184.99.163.554 2.176.241.217 221.181.185.135 221.181.185.148 45.141.84.126 49.88.112.77
```

All the banned IPs were manually added using `fail2ban-client set sshd banip <IP>`.

Jail:

```
[sshd]
mode     = aggressive
filter   = sshd
port     = ssh
logpath  = %(sshd_log)s
backend  = %(sshd_backend)s
enabled  = true
maxretry = 1
```

Using the default sshd definition:

```
# cat /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf  | grep -v ^#  | grep .
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf
[DEFAULT]
_daemon = sshd
__pref = (?:(?:error|fatal): (?:PAM: )?)?
__suff = (?: (?:port \d+|on \S+|\[preauth\])){0,3}\s*
__on_port_opt = (?: (?:port \d+|on \S+)){0,2}
__authng_user = (?: (?:invalid|authenticating) user <F-USER>\S+|.+?</F-USER>)?
__alg_match = (?:(?:\w+ (?!found\b)){0,2}\w+)
__pam_auth = pam_[a-z]+
[Definition]
prefregex = ^<F-MLFID>%(__prefix_line)s</F-MLFID>%(__pref)s<F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$
cmnfailre = ^[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error|failed) for <F-USER>.*</F-USER> from <HOST>( via \S+)?%(__suff)s$
            ^User not known to the underlying authentication module for <F-USER>.*</F-USER> from <HOST>%(__suff)s$
            ^Failed publickey for invalid user <F-USER>(?P<cond_user>\S+)|(?:(?! from ).)*?</F-USER> from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s(?: ssh\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)
            ^Failed \b(?!publickey)\S+ for (?P<cond_inv>invalid user )?<F-USER>(?P<cond_user>\S+)|(?(cond_inv)(?:(?! from ).)*?|[^:]+)</F-USER> from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s(?: ssh\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)
            ^<F-USER>ROOT</F-USER> LOGIN REFUSED FROM <HOST>
            ^[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user <F-USER>.*?</F-USER> from <HOST>%(__suff)s$
            ^User <F-USER>.+</F-USER> from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers%(__suff)s$
            ^User <F-USER>.+</F-USER> from <HOST> not allowed because listed in DenyUsers%(__suff)s$
            ^User <F-USER>.+</F-USER> from <HOST> not allowed because not in any group%(__suff)s$
            ^refused connect from \S+ \(<HOST>\)
            ^Received <F-MLFFORGET>disconnect</F-MLFFORGET> from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s:\s*3: .*: Auth fail%(__suff)s$
            ^User <F-USER>.+</F-USER> from <HOST> not allowed because a group is listed in DenyGroups%(__suff)s$
            ^User <F-USER>.+</F-USER> from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups%(__suff)s$
            ^<F-NOFAIL>%(__pam_auth)s\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;</F-NOFAIL>(?:\s+(?:(?:logname|e?uid|tty)=\S*)){0,4}\s+ruser=<F-ALT_USER>\S*</F-ALT_USER>\s+rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=<F-USER>\S*</F-USER>)?%(__suff)s$
            ^(error: )?maximum authentication attempts exceeded for <F-USER>.*</F-USER> from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s(?: ssh\d*)?%(__suff)s$
            ^User <F-USER>.+</F-USER> not allowed because account is locked%(__suff)s
            ^<F-MLFFORGET>Disconnecting</F-MLFFORGET>(?: from)?(?: (?:invalid|authenticating)) user <F-USER>\S+</F-USER> <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s:\s*Change of username or service not allowed:\s*.*\[preauth\]\s*$
            ^<F-MLFFORGET>Disconnecting</F-MLFFORGET>: Too many authentication failures(?: for <F-USER>.+?</F-USER>)?%(__suff)s$
            ^<F-NOFAIL>Received <F-MLFFORGET>disconnect</F-MLFFORGET></F-NOFAIL> from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s:\s*11:
            <mdre-<mode>-other>
            ^<F-MLFFORGET><F-MLFGAINED>Accepted \w+</F-MLFGAINED></F-MLFFORGET> for <F-USER>\S+</F-USER> from <HOST>(?:\s|$)
mdre-normal =
mdre-normal-other = ^<F-NOFAIL><F-MLFFORGET>(Connection closed|Disconnected)</F-MLFFORGET></F-NOFAIL> (?:by|from)%(__authng_user)s <HOST>(?:%(__suff)s|\s*)$
mdre-ddos = ^Did not receive identification string from <HOST>
            ^Bad protocol version identification '.*' from <HOST>
            ^Connection <F-MLFFORGET>reset</F-MLFFORGET> by <HOST>
            ^<F-NOFAIL>SSH: Server;Ltype:</F-NOFAIL> (?:Authname|Version|Kex);Remote: <HOST>-\d+;[A-Z]\w+:
            ^Read from socket failed: Connection <F-MLFFORGET>reset</F-MLFFORGET> by peer
mdre-ddos-other = ^<F-MLFFORGET>(Connection closed|Disconnected)</F-MLFFORGET> (?:by|from)%(__authng_user)s <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s\s+\[preauth\]\s*$
mdre-extra = ^Received <F-MLFFORGET>disconnect</F-MLFFORGET> from <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s:\s*14: No supported authentication methods available
            ^Unable to negotiate with <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s: no matching <__alg_match> found.
            ^Unable to negotiate a <__alg_match>
            ^no matching <__alg_match> found:
mdre-extra-other = ^<F-MLFFORGET>Disconnected</F-MLFFORGET>(?: from)?(?: (?:invalid|authenticating)) user <F-USER>\S+|.*?</F-USER> <HOST>%(__on_port_opt)s \[preauth\]\s*$
mdre-aggressive = %(mdre-ddos)s
                  %(mdre-extra)s
mdre-aggressive-other = %(mdre-ddos-other)s
cfooterre = ^<F-NOFAIL>Connection from</F-NOFAIL> <HOST>
failregex = %(cmnfailre)s
            <mdre-<mode>>
            %(cfooterre)s
mode = aggressive
ignoreregex =
maxlines = 1
journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd
```

The filter seems to match the regexes (>3000 matches):

```
# fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : sshd, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         maxlines : 1
Use      datepattern : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /var/log/auth.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 4571 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [942] ^[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error|failed) for <F-USER>.*</F-USER> from <HOST>( via \S+)?(?: (?:port \d+|on \S+|\[preauth\])){0,3}\s*$
|   4) [84] ^Failed \b(?!publickey)\S+ for (?P<cond_inv>invalid user )?<F-USER>(?P<cond_user>\S+)|(?(cond_inv)(?:(?! from ).)*?|[^:]+)</F-USER> from <HOST>(?: (?:port \d+|on \S+)){0,2}(?: ssh\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)
|   6) [843] ^[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user <F-USER>.*?</F-USER> from <HOST>(?: (?:port \d+|on \S+|\[preauth\])){0,3}\s*$
|  14) [942] ^<F-NOFAIL>pam_[a-z]+\(sshd:auth\):\s+authentication failure;</F-NOFAIL>(?:\s+(?:(?:logname|e?uid|tty)=\S*)){0,4}\s+ruser=<F-ALT_USER>\S*</F-ALT_USER>\s+rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=<F-USER>\S*</F-USER>)?(?: (?:port \d+|on \S+|\[preauth\])){0,3}\s*$
|  19) [402] ^<F-NOFAIL>Received <F-MLFFORGET>disconnect</F-MLFFORGET></F-NOFAIL> from <HOST>(?: (?:port \d+|on \S+)){0,2}:\s*11:
|  20) [1329] ^<F-MLFFORGET>(Connection closed|Disconnected)</F-MLFFORGET> (?:by|from)(?: (?:invalid|authenticating) user <F-USER>\S+|.+?</F-USER>)? <HOST>(?: (?:port \d+|on \S+)){0,2}\s+\[preauth\]\s*$
|  21) [8] ^<F-MLFFORGET><F-MLFGAINED>Accepted \w+</F-MLFGAINED></F-MLFFORGET> for <F-USER>\S+</F-USER> from <HOST>(?:\s|$)
|  24) [6] ^Connection <F-MLFFORGET>reset</F-MLFFORGET> by <HOST>
|  28) [15] ^Unable to negotiate with <HOST>(?: (?:port \d+|on \S+)){0,2}: no matching (?:(?:\w+ (?!found\b)){0,2}\w+) found.
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [5185] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 5185 lines, 1352 ignored, 3216 matched, 617 missed
[processed in 0.34 sec]

Ignored line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-ignored to print all 1352 lines
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 617 lines
```

But no matter what happens, no IPs are getting banned!

* adding that I've set the following in `sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and added Google 2FA in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth    required        pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Comment: Have you check this thread? https://serverfault.com/questions/686422/modify-fail2ban-failregex-to-match-failed-public-key-authentications-via-ssh/686436

Comment: Yes @Angel115. Thanks. However, in my case, the regex is catching the failures, but nothing happens

Comment: Since it doesn't catched any failure, something basical seems to be wrong here (either backend is systemd, so it is monitoring journal, or something similar)... 
You have to provide a dump of fail2ban-client stream to check what may happen there:
fail2ban-client -d | grep sshd.